# Is "I do" applicable in this song lyric?

Tags: lyrics

Is it correct to say:

> I'm feeling like the day I thought I could make great things happen.
> Because I do.

"I do" referring to "make great things happen". I'm feeling this way again because now I realize I'm a person that does make great things happen.

It's for a song...

Comment: It's correct, but it's not very clear.  "Because I do" what?  Feel like it?  Think it?  It would be much clearer if you wrote "Because I do make them happen."

Comment: By "the day" do you mean "today"?

Comment: You are feeling like a day? How is a person like a day? Are you 24 hours long, beginning and ending in darkness? Maybe you feel that it is the day.

Answer (score 1):

It could be considered okay, but there might be better ways to say it (it sounds a little confusing, but then again, maybe for a song lyric that’s okay).

Other ways of saying it.

> Because I can. (You know you can because you’ve already done it.)

Or:

> Because I am (making great things happen).

I also feel there may be a bit of a discrepancy around feeling like the day you thought you could (tentative/uncertain) when in the present you actually are (or know you can) (absolute/declarative/certain).